# Is it halal to crash or go into a wedding without invitation in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, food, wedding

I want to ask that is it Halal or Haram to go into a unknown wedding without invitation?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is haram to attend a wedding (walima) or other party to which you have not been invited.

> #### يا أيها الذين آمنوا لا تدخلوا بيوت النبي إلا أن يؤذن لكم إلى طعام غير ناظرين إناه ولكن إذا دعيتم فادخلوا
>
> O you who have believed, do not enter the houses of the Prophet except when you are permitted for a meal, without awaiting its readiness. But when you are invited, then enter;
>
> <sup>— [Quran 33:53](http://quran.com/33/53) - see [Tafsir Ibn Kathir](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/katheer/sura33-aya53.html#katheer): وهذا دليل على تحريم التطفيل</sup>

> ومن دخل على غير دعوة دخل سارقا، وخرج مغيرا
>
> He who enters without invitation enters as a thief and goes out as a raider.
>
> <sup>— [Sunan Abi Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3741)</sup>

Note that this is the ruling for the base case; it is permitted when the host has declared a general invitation to all people, or when he has allowed an uninvited guest or when when it is implicitly known that he consents to it.

---

**Reference:**

> صرح المالكية والشافعية والحنابلة - وهو المتبادر من أقوال الحنفية - أن حضور طعام الغير بغير دعوة، وبغير علم رضاه حرام، بل يفسق به إن تكرر
>
> The Malikis, Shafi'is and Hanbalis have declared - and it is also understood from the sayings of the Hanafis - that attending a banquet without invitation and without knowing the consent of the host, is haram and one who does so repeatedly becomes a fasiq
>
> <sup>— [Encyclopedia of Islamic Jurisprudence](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/7277#p1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In Saudi Arabia, I have attended major weddings involving families that were not known to me without a prior invitation. From this experience, it seems that it would not therefore be haram otherwise I would have been strongly advised against it by Saudi friends and colleagues.

In regard to UmH's answer, however, I should specify that the weddings were not inside a house.